# EF Core: add attributes to entity properties at scaffold time?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Using EF Core database-first, when we have made changes to the database schema, we delete all entity classes and the context and scaffold everything from scratch by calling `Scaffold-DbContext`.

I want to add an attribute to a given entity properties at scaffold time, driven by the database column names. So, a simple array would do as configuration:

```
// I want the properties mapped to these properties to be generated decorated with e.g. `MyAttribute`
var columnsToDecorate = new[] { "dbo.Users.Name", "dbo.Users.Email" };
```

Is there a hook to do this?

I am using EF Core v3.1.15 if it makes any difference.

Comment: I wanted something similar and figured the fastest way to do it was to approach the maker of the extension I used for doing the scaff, EFCPT (which was the extension), and ask if the post-processing module could be used to add the attributes I needed (I think it was storing enums as text rather than numbers). Erik (the maker of EFCPT) said no, but it's open source so I cloned it and did it anyway and have used it since, to retrieve some JSON stored the the DB's column Description field, to control the generation/add the attribute. EFC3.1 is deprecated now but the old version I hacked the ..

Comment: ...functionality into might still work with such an ancient EFC. Let me know if you'd be interested in looking at it and I'll dig it out. For now, perhaps someone will come along with an actual answer (but EFCPT does make most EFC work a good chunk nicer IMHO)

Comment: If you are willing to upgrade to EF Core 7 (and I highly recommend you to) then you can use the [Custom Reverse Engineering Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/templates?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) feature which allows to customize the scaffolding based on T4 templates.